# TGV from Strasbourg to Paris is cheaper if starting from Karlsruhe. Why?

Tags: trains, germany, france

I want to travel from Strasbourg to Paris in October and found a price for 2 passengers for around €314 return.

I then found a connection from Karlsruhe (Germany) and got a price of €240 return. I'm 99% sure that the train stops in Strasbourg on the way.

Traveling via Karlsruhe would easily add over 2 hours to my journey. Strasbourg is closer for me (I live in Germany)

Why the price difference? Are there any restrictions for boarding in Strasbourg?

[Prices from voyages-sncf.com and bahn.de are very similar]

Comment: Are you sure that the price is for the same type of ticket? I'd imagine that the cheaper one is a discount price where you have to choose a specific train at time of booking (Sparpreis Europa Frankreich in DB-language).

Comment: Also depending on the exact date in October, you might be affected by the track closure between Karlsruhe and Strasbourg. At the moment all connections from Karlsruhe to Paris run through Saarbrücken.

Comment: @martin.koeberl - same web site, same seach (except for starting station), same cancellation policy - so identical conditions it seems

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer your first question: If you compare the regular prices to each other, you will see that a one-way ticket Strasbourg-Paris is 93€ while a one-way ticket Karlsruhe-Paris costs 114€, so as expected the longer trip costs more. It seems to me that the ticket prices you quote are for discount tickets (which at SNCF you can find in the first and the second column):[image: Different ticket prices for a connection from Strasbourg to Paris]

These discount tickets are only available on some (and not an all) routes and their availability is limited. They are sold on a first-come-first-served basis, so either there are no discount tickets for most trains from Strasbourg to Paris or they are already sold out (at least the cheapest ones). Also there availability might be different between SNCF and DB.

Luckily for you, it seems SNCF allows you to board the train in Strasbourg when you have a ticket Karlsruhe-Paris. This is supported by a certified answer on [Questions SNCF](http://questions.sncf.com/questions/1004667-gare-desservie-train-gare-depart).

Note though that according to above link if you have a seat reservation and you don't take your seat at the origin of the reservation, the conductor might give your seat to somebody else. I'm not sure whether you can buy a separate seat reservation with SNCF but SNCF only sells a limited number of tickets without assigned seat, so you might find a seat anyway.

Please note though that different rules might apply to trains in international traffic between Germany and France. I couldn't find anything though limiting above answer to only national trains.

Comment: (+1) I seem to recall that the 15-min rule for seat reservation is a DB rule and doesn't really exist in France. Do you know if that's the case? And how SNCF and DB rules might interact for an international train?

Comment: @Relaxed Oh, I stumbled upon this yesterday and couldn't remember anymore whether it was about DB or SNCF. The answer on Questions SNCF I linked to touches upon this issue though.
It could very well be that the rules are different for international travel, but I couldn't find anything about it yet.

Answer (score -3):

If you look at the map, you will see that the way from Karlsruhe to Paris does *not* go through Strasburg, not even near it. It is actually a shorter distance, so cheaper makes sense.

Comment: (-1) That's mostly irrelevant and simply untrue. Trains might or might not go through Saarbrücken at the moment (cf. comments) but the regular route to Karlsruhe has always been through Strasbourg since the East European High-Speed Line opened. Even trains going as far north are Frankfurt are faster through Strasbourg as they can use faster lines all the way (but in this case, there are also a few trains going through Saarbrücken).

Comment: I did think about this and checked the plan. The train stops once - in Strasbourg.

Comment: @Relaxed: The consideration as such is not completely irrelevant. As a passenger, I usually do not care where the tracks run and whether we geographically do a detour to an intermediate stop. I only care about the overall aerial distance bridged and want to pay according to that.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Well, the assumption here is that the train must take the shortest route and does not go through Strasbourg at all, which is clearly false. That's why it's irrelevant in this case. But more broadly, I don't see why you would care at all *as a passenger*, what's relevant are the options available to you. What would you do if it felt more expensive than it ought to according to your system? Take a taxi out of spite? Also, “mostly” != “completely”.

Comment: @Relaxed: "What would you do if it felt more expensive than it ought to according to your system? Take a taxi out of spite?" - when, as a customer, I have the impression that a product is overpriced, I will buy it less often than I otherwise would.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper OK, so you're deciding whether Paris is worth a visit based on minute details of the train companies pricing policy? That's an interesting outlook on life…

Comment: @Relaxed: If, out of two places A and B, transportation to place A is unreasonably expensive, and transportation to place B is not, then I will certainly factor that into my decision on whether to travel to A or to B, obviously. As always, a part of a buying decision is based on whether the price seems justifyable.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Unreasonably expensive compared to what? Would you forgo going to A even if going to B is more actually expensive? If A is more interesting and cheaper to go to than B, what does the “justifiability” matter? Conversely if you just mean you'd rather go to a cheaper place, I get it, but that has absolutely nothing to do with the relationship between distance and price.

Comment: @Relaxed: "Would you forgo going to A even if going to B is more actually expensive?" - yes. It's not about picking the cheapest offer, but about not paying more for something than what it is worth (i.e. presumed production cost to get exactly what you want - in this case, bridging the distance from point 1 to point 2 -, plus some small profit margin for the vendor). As I said above, it is not the only criterion, though, so interestingness of a place might indeed overrule the price/distance consideration. I now wonder how you evaluate the price of products, but I think it leads off-topic.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That's a self-defeating notion of worth. You're actually inflicting damage on yourself, forgoing something that by your own admission is worth more to you (i.e. is more interesting) to enforce your notion of how trains should be priced. It's not something of interest to you *as a passenger* but only as a moralist.

Comment: By contrast, the way I try to evaluate the price of products is rational and straightforward: Do you I want to go there/how much pleasure will I derive from it? Is it this cheapest way to go there or are there alternatives? Is there some other place with a better interest/price ratio or some other use for my money that seems more rewarding? The margin of the vendor or some abstract comparison between trains journeys I don't want to make do not enter the decision at all.

Comment: @Relaxed: Sorry, readily paying whatever is charged for the seemingly cheapest alternative without any further thought does not seem rational to me, but I guess to each their own.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper But it is the cheapest alternatively, it's not “seemingly” cheapest, that's the crux of the matter! And it's not about readily paying without further thought, it's about thinking about the right variables: other means of transportation, other destinations, other activities, spending vs. saving, without losing time on irrelevant things that I cannot influence. In this discussion, you're the one acting impulsively on a feeling of fairness instead of clearly evaluating the parameters of your decision.

Comment: Let's look at it from another angle: What if the price satisfies your arbitrary notion of what it costs to provide transportation? What if the company is losing money? Your income hasn't changed, it's not easier for you to pay for it. Paris hasn't changed, it's still as interesting or boring as it was before. You literally get the same mileage out of your money and you have provided no reason why it would be rational to care about anything else *as a passenger*. Doing otherwise and going to B is akin to buying a gadget you don't need because there is a big shinny “20% discount” sign.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66383/discussion-between-relaxed-and-o-r-mapper).